# How can I disable the truncated numbers mode added in 2.4 Update?

Tags: diablo-iii

I updated to 2.4, and it now shows numbers as truncated numbers (10m rather than 10,000,000). It is really bothering me and I want to disable it, can I do it? If so, how can I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can disable it!**

1. Open the Game Menu by pressing the Esc button.

[image: Game Menu]

2. Open the Options menu

[image: Options Button]

3. Switch to the Gameplay Tab

[image: Gameplay Tab]

4. Tick the "Display Long Floating Combat Numbers" button (it is Unticked in the picture)

[image: The "Display Long Floating Combat Numbers" Button]

Enjoy the long numbers!